# JQuery Conflicts using nestedsortable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery nested sortable plugin for drag and drop functionality in my site. I have some Javascript included in my main layout which is creating problems with drag and drop.
The JS files included are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/jq/jquery-1.7.2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/jquery.dropdownPlain.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/ui.core.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/ui.tabs.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/tools.scrollable.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/tools.scrollable.circular.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/tools.scrollable.navigator.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/tools.scrollable.autoscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/tools.tabs-1.0.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/jquery.color.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/jquery.panda.js') }}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/theblock/jquery.prettyPhoto.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/jq/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/nestedsortable.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/munichinnovationgroup/js/dragdrop.js') }}"></script>
```

When I try to drag an item I see this error in my console

```
TypeError: this.helper.scrollParent is not a function
```

in jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js (line 37)

Any idea which file is creating conflict and how can I remove it

thanks

Comment: You are loading two jQuery UI libraries.

Comment: I am loading jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js which on is the other ?

Comment: What is the `ui.core.pack.js`?